# Peer Gossip "reportMembershipChanges" keeps on changing and one of the peers in the network keeps going offline and comes alive again

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have a hyperledger Fabric network were 5 organizations are participating in one channel. Recently one of the peers keeps going offline and comes alive again. this is causing some transactions from other peer to fail when this peer is down, since I have a private data dissemination policy which enforce the data to be disseminated to this peer.

Here are the logs of the gossip from other peer nodes in the network:

```
2021-08-05 13:07:24.427 UTC [gossip.comm] func1 -> WARN 080 peer0.dcc.dxb.com:7051, PKIid:59f9c45bf431c6dcfd9bdd8daabff772f6302a23e1769ef9c740d970c24588f8 isn't responsive: EOF
2021-08-05 13:07:24.427 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 081 Entering [59f9c45bf431c6dcfd9bdd8daabff772f6302a23e1769ef9c740d970c24588f8]
2021-08-05 13:07:24.427 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 082 Closing connection to Endpoint: peer0.dcc.dxb.com:7051, InternalEndpoint: , PKI-ID: 59f9c45bf431c6dcfd9bdd8daabff772f6302a23e1769ef9c740d970c24588f8, Metadata:
2021-08-05 13:07:24.427 UTC [gossip.discovery] expireDeadMembers -> WARN 083 Exiting

2021-08-05 13:07:24.625 UTC [gossip.channel] reportMembershipChanges -> INFO 085 [[urchannel] Membership view has changed. peers went offline:  [[peer0.dcc.dxb.com:7051 ]] , current view:  [[peer0.org1.com:7051 ] [peer0.org2.com:7051 ] [peer0.org3.dxb.com:7051 ]]]
```

I can see from the logs that the peer is not responsive and then it goes offline. Any idea why this is happening ?
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you changed a certificate of one of the peers recently? And what Fabric version are you using?

Comment: I didn't change the certificates, but I upgraded the network from fabric-1.4.7 to Fabric-2.3.1. this upgrade includes upgrading the binaries and the configurations such as capabilities but not the certificates.

Comment: Also please note that many of the transactions are going through. The transaction fails only if the discovery service is not able to communicate with the peer(peer become irresponsive)

Comment: try to turn off the peer for an hour, then start it back again

Comment: this is a production environment and there is no downtime allowed, still i will try it over the weekend since this is considered a down time. but what is the logic behind it.

Comment: The logic behind it is to make the identity purged from the memory of all peers. Did you somehow perhaps change ip address between two peers? Like, peerA.org1 became peerB.org1 and vice versa?

Comment: Nothing has been changed from the network perspective. I will try it over the weekend. thanks for the reply, appreciated.

Comment: Hi Yacovm,  I tried to turn of the peer for more than one hour, but it didn't work the issue is still there.  Also to answer your question "peerA.org1 became peerB.org1 and vice versa?". I am not sure if i did this, but in case this happened  what will be the effect and how to resolve it.